# Opensteer project file conversion and compilation

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Opensteer is a library which aims to provide agent behaviors for real time games.

I tried to compile it, but I have an error and I have no clue what it means. When I click on it, it opens a MSVC file.

```
Error   3   error MSB3073: The command "mkdir "C:\opensteer\win32\\lib"
copy "C:\opensteer\win32\Debug\opensteer.lib" "C:\opensteer\win32\\lib"

:VCEnd" exited with code 1. C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 113
```

I've no idea why there is somehow a folder name thing missing between the two `\\`

It's only the source package provided here http://sourceforge.net/projects/opensteer/files/opensteer/OpenSteer%200.8.2/

Comment: Which studio edition ? 2012 ?

Comment: MSVC 2010, sorry, forgot to mention.